# Getting RSSI value -11 is it correct?

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, rssi

I am working with an app that collects data( rssi value, beacon id, minor, major) from ibeacon and calculates distance. I am getting rssi value about -11  and so distance 0.0 always. is this correct rssi value? I am using altbeacon library. what is the min and max value of rssi value of ibeacon ?

Comment: "I am getting rssi value about -11 and so distance 0.0 **always**", you mean, regardless of the actual distance? That would definitely look suspicious, and maybe the Bluetooth stack in that particular smartphone simply reports RSSI incorrectly higher up the stack. (I've seen this happen with 0 RSSI, although never with -11.) Maybe try another smartphone to verify if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

RSSI is measured in dBm, and in this case measures the strength of the signal at the receiver.  The stronger the signal, the less negative the value will be.  A value of -11 indicates an extremely strong signal.

Bluetooth Low Energy normally has limits on the strength of the transmission imposed by international radio regulatory agencies.  A Bluetooth LE beacon transmitter that is compliant with these regulations should never put out a signal that is stronger than about -55 dBm when measured one meter away.

Moving the receiver closer to the transmitter will increase the strength of the received signal.  In theory, moving from 1 meter away to 0 meters away should increase the signal by about +41 dB.  This might make the maximum expected theoretical signal level at 0 meters away be read as -14 dBm.  (In practice, it is impossible to get an actual distance of 0 meters -- you always have some finite distance between transmitter and receiver.)

Bottom line:  A RSSI value of -11, even if measured when the receiver is touching the transmitter, is unexpectedly strong.  Two possibilities:

1. The beacon transmitter is stronger than allowed by international regulatory agencies. (Unlikely)
2. **Something is wrong with the RSSI sensor on the receiving device.**  There may be a problem with the Analog to Digital converter or there may be a problem with the firmware that sends the digital reading to software upstream.  (Most likely)

Answer (score 0):

To complement David's answer, an iBeacon-compatible beacon will provide a value (if configured correctly) that expresses the perceived power/RSSI when the beacon is 1 meter away. Sadly this value is often set wrong, but can provide a hint of what you should expect. It's often set to -59 dBm by default.

-11 dBm is in any case a very high power value. I just tested with a beacon set to 0 dBm and when it's very close to the phone it shows an RSSI of -36 dBm that AltBeacon translates as "immediate". 1 meter away I get "near".

I use the same library via a Cordova plugin, so I doubt AltBeacon is in the wrong in your case.